# How do I best display LED strips so the bulbs are hidden from sight?

Tags: interior, led, recessed-lighting

I want to put this [LED strip](http://www.tradexguru.com/led-floodlight-rgb-sensors-interior-accent-exterior-accent-signature-lighting/led-strip-lighting/led-strip-lighting-kits/150-led-5m-rgb-strip-tape-lighting-5m-multicolour-waterproof-strip-fishtank-interior-exterior-accent.html) in my room, which is a box shaped room with white walls.

[image]

I am sure I am supposed to hide the LED strip lighting, but I am at a loss on how to make a suitable coving or box to hide the messy strip bit.  How would I do that?

Comment: Where in the room? ceiling? walls? Facing up or facing down.  We need more information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cove or crown molding that is below (free from) the ceiling by 2-4 Inches will give a subdued look.  I would place the strip on the wall just below the aperture of the molding (that slit exposed by lowering the molding).  Some installations I've seen use a separate wall trim that angles the light strip up..IE attach a wooden strip behind and below the crown, attach the LED strip to the 45 block.
[image]
[image]